# Watson Conversation API, output_message doesnt change

Tags: php, watson, php-curl

I am using the Watson Conversation API with a simple PHP/Curl code. I ask questions and I can tell the questions get correctly to Watson because the "intent" changes. But the output message is always the same.

```
$input = array("text"=>$_GET["msg"]);
$return["input"] = (object)$input;
if(strlen($_GET["context"])>0){
    $context = array("conversation_id"=>$_GET["context"]);
    $return["context"] = (object) $context;
}
$return = (object) $return;
$json = json_encode($return);
echo $json;
echo "<br><hr><br>";
$ch = curl_init("https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/conversation/api/v1/workspaces/d5ee17e9-9e19-bca5-765870f31816/message?version=2018-02-16");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json  );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($json))
    );       
$output = curl_exec($ch);       
echo "<pre>".$output."</pre>";
```

HERE IS THE ANSWER I GET:

`{
    "intents": [
        {
            "intent": "capabilities",
            "confidence": 1
        }
    ],
    "entities": [],
    "input": {
        "text": "what can you do"
    },
    "output": {
        "text": [
            "Hi. It looks like a nice drive today. What would you like me to do? "
        ],
        "nodes_visited": [
            "Start And Initialize Context"
        ],
        "log_messages": []
    },
    "context": {
        "conversation_id": "cbb41b48-addb-4d42-a146-39a4550caaaf",
        "system": {
            "dialog_stack": [
                {
                    "dialog_node": "root"
                }
            ],
            "dialog_turn_counter": 1,
            "dialog_request_counter": 1,
            "_node_output_map": {
                "Start And Initialize Context": [
                    0,
                    0
                ]
            },
            "branch_exited": true,
            "branch_exited_reason": "completed"
        },
        "AConoff": "off",
        "lightonoff": "off",
        "musiconoff": "off",
        "appl_action": "",
        "heateronoff": "off",
        "volumeonoff": "off",
        "wipersonoff": "off",
        "default_counter": 0
    }
    }`

As you can see, the message_output is a random greeting. Regardless of the question i make, i get the same text.

Comment: You dont need to cast everything to an object, if you send the same message it will respond with the same answer but slightly different, you ask `what can you do` it ask `What would you like me to do?` you should then use the conversation_id to continue the conversation but if its anything like api.ai you need to have intents/entities setup correctly, or it borks out and starts again.

Comment: Lawrence, thaks for taking your time. The object casting was just laziness, but regarding the question, i store the `conversation_id` and i pass it along. I can tell watson identifies my question, because it gets the `intent`. but the point is *regardless of the intent that watson identifies, it always returns the same "what would you like me to do" answer*